# How to log dynamic values for the tags in micrometer DistributionSummary

Tags: prometheus, micrometer

I would like to log dynamic tag values for the DistrbutionSummary metric, how can I do that?

in the below example, there is a tag called myTag, and I would like to log the value of the tag on the fly according to the data received. there could be multiple tags I want to log the distribution summary for and I would not know those tag values unless in real time.

```
DistributionSummary histogram = DistributionSummary.builder("my_histogram")
            .description("Example histogram")
            .baseUnit("ms")
            .publishPercentiles(0.5, 0.95)
            .tags("myTag", "myTagVal")
            .serviceLevelObjectives(100.0, 500.0, 1000.0)
            .distributionStatisticExpiry(Duration.ofMinutes(5))
            .distributionStatisticBufferLength(3)
            .register(meterRegistry);
```

For eg., Metrics.counter from micrometer has a way to pass the value for the tags on the fly while incrementing or recording the value. how can we do the same in DistributionSummary?

```
Metrics.counter("eventsProcessed", "myTag", anyValue).increment(count);
```

Comment: Be advised that [label with unlimited number of possible values is potentially damaging to the performance of you Prometheus setup](https://prometheus.io/docs/practices/instrumentation/#do-not-overuse-labels).

Comment: Thanks, I am expecting only handful like 10-20. So I do not see any cardinality issues

Answer (score 2):

Basically same way you just did in your question. :)

```java
DistributionSummary.builder("test.distribution")
        .tag("static", "abc")
        .tag("dynamic", tagValue) // comes from a variable dynamically
        .register(meterRegistry)
        .record(value);
```

`register` basically means `createNewOrGetExsisting`. Also, since Micrometer 1.12.0, we have a [shortcut](https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/micrometer/pull/4097) for this:

```java
MeterProvider<DistributionSummary> distributionProvider = DistributionSummary.builder("test.distribution")
        .tag("static", "abc")
        .withRegistry(registry);

// [...]

distributionProvider.withTags(Tags.of("dynamic", tagValue)).record(value);
```

A few other thoughts:

- What you did with the `Counter` is also possible with the `DistributionSummary`: `registry.summary("test", "dynamic", tagValue).record(value);`
- Since seemingly you are measuring latency, I would highly recommend using a `Timer` instead, [here's why](https://develotters.com/posts/how-not-to-measure-elapsed-time/)
- As others also advised before, please double-check if you don;t have high-cardinality tags (unnormalized user input included), [here's why](https://develotters.com/posts/high-cardinality/)

Answer (score -1):

I happened to encounter this issue and found a solution by reading the source code. You can achieve dynamic adjustment using the following approach. Here is the pseudocode:

```
private final String LISTED_MARKET_SSE = "SSE";
private final String LISTED_MARKET_SZE = "SZE";

@Override
public void bindTo(@NonNull MeterRegistry meterRegistry) {
    String tagListedMarket = "listed_market";
    String upstream7101LatencyName = "kafkaConsumer.upstream.7101.latency";
    upstream7101LatencySummary = DistributionSummary.builder(upstream7101LatencyName)
            .baseUnit("ms")
            .tag(tagListedMarket, "")
            .publishPercentiles(0.99, 0.95, 0.5)
            .register(meterRegistry);
    upstream7101LatencySummarySZE = DistributionSummary.builder(upstream7101LatencyName)
            .baseUnit("ms")
            .tag(tagListedMarket, LISTED_MARKET_SZE)
            .publishPercentiles(0.99, 0.95, 0.5)
            .register(meterRegistry);
    upstream7101LatencySummarySSE = DistributionSummary.builder(upstream7101LatencyName)
            .baseUnit("ms")
            .tag(tagListedMarket, LISTED_MARKET_SSE)
            .publishPercentiles(0.99, 0.95, 0.5)
            .register(meterRegistry);
}
```

then use：

```
    if (LISTED_MARKET_SSE.equals(listedMarket)) {
        upstream7101LatencySummarySSE.record(amount);
    }
    else if (LISTED_MARKET_SZE.equals(listedMarket)) {
        upstream7101LatencySummarySZE.record(amount);
    }
    else {
        upstream7101LatencySummary.record(amount);
    }
```